# Would like to understand this re js merging arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I was given a coding challenge for a job interview and I would like to see if there are any good deed doers who might help me see where I went wrong. I couldn't even understand the general question that was being asked so I would like to know if anyone feels the same way. This is the whole question:

A simplified version of HTML can be represented by using arrays to represent elements:

```
[tagName, child1, child2, ...]
```

• The tag name is always the first entry in the array and is a string.
• The children can be either arrays or strings.
• If the child is a string it is treated as plain text, not HTML markup.
• If the child is an array it is treated as a nested element.
• There is no support for attributes, comments, etc., just elements and text.
Implement a JavaScript function that takes an array and generates the HTML string.
• Empty tags should be self-closing.
• Consecutive text nodes are merged in the finished output.
• No libraries, build processes or transpilers.
Examples:

```
['div'] => '<div/>'
['h1', 'Text'] => '<h1>Text</h1>'
['span', 'More', 'Text'] => '<span>MoreText</span>'
['a', ['b', 'More'], ' Text'] => '<a><b>More</b> Text</a>'
['p', '<b>Text</b>'] => '<p>&lt;b&gt;Text&lt;/b&gt;</p>'
```

My answer was the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title here</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<style>
div{
background: yellow;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<h1>I am a <br>header</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<div></div>
</section>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"The title of this document is: " + document.title;
</script>

<script>
```

var wrapper = document.createElement("div");

```
wrapper.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Part 1 ") );
wrapper.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Part 2 ") );

// At this point, wrapper.childNodes.length === 2
wrapper.childNodes[0].textContent === "Part 1 "
wrapper.childNodes[1].textContent === "Part 2 "

wrapper.normalize();

// Now, wrapper.childNodes.length === 1
wrapper.childNodes[0].textContent === "Part 1 Part 2 "   

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I did see that my text wasn't merged; but I thought I followed the rest of the requirements. I found the requirements a little hard to understand. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  You start your question talking about the array describing the page and generating the page from the array, yet I don't see such an array any where in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the question is asking you

- Write a function that takes an array.
- The array can contain strings, or tags (div's, p, etc.)
- write a function that iterates the array, appending to the dom, the elements and the strings.
- You are always going to get the first tag name, as the container, everything following should be inside of the first tag [div, 'hey', p, 'paragraph'] =>

  `div
  hey
  p paragraph p
  div`

  Does that make more sense, it's how i am interpreting the question. Had to take out the <> so formatting was more clear

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. Its the little things that can make all the difference! I totally didn't see that until you pointed out where I was not reading the question. much thanx :)